# import dependency from a pom file without using inheritance

Tags: maven, inheritance, dependencies

I want to import some dependencies from a pom file to another pom file without using inheritance, 
For example i have project A with a pom file, and a module of this project called B, so my question is how to import dependencies existing in B pom file to A pom file without using inheritance.

Comment: It should be enough when B depends on A (for transitive dependencies)

Comment: do you mean to use it as a module ?

Comment: Let's start again: why do you want have B dependencies in A project? Because mainstream concept is that project should define it's dependencies itself. Let say B use libraryX and with some magic A also use libraryX. Then B decide to change to libraryY and A no longer compile. Summary: if option you want exists it will kill maintainability because changing dependency list will never be safe

Comment: Right, so i will keep dependency in each project. Thanks michaldo.